# Local de instalação do Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

Como eu faço para mudar o caminho onde é instalado meu Genymotion?

Eu uso HD externo e instalei tudo do Android Studio nele. Quando eu instalei o Genymotion Plugin, não foi criada uma pasta C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion e, quando eu tento abrir o plugin, ele pede pra localizar a pasta mas não acho de jeito nenhum.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Localiza primeiro o local de instalação do Genymotion, copia o caminho depois e cola no android studio bem nessa parte da imagem.